# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when filling 2d array with user input

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code I have currentlly.

```
public static void testClosestToMean() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rows does your array have: ");
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns does your array have: ");
    int columns = input.nextInt();

    double[][] numbers = new double[rows][columns];


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a value for your array: ");
            double values = input.nextDouble();
            numbers[rows][columns] = values;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my program I reach `System.out.println("Enter a value for your array: ");` however when I  input a single number and press enter this error occurs:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I'm just generally stuck and would like guidance or even an explanation of why this error keeps occurring.

Comment: numbers[rows][columns] = values; => numbers[i][j] = values;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indices of your 2D array run from `0` to `row-1` for the rows and `0` to `columns-1` for the columns. However, you'r trying to access `numbers[rows][columns]` which is known as an "off-by-one error" because your accessing indices that are each one more than the max possible index. If you want to fix this, then replace `rows` with `i` and `columns` with `j` like so,

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a value for your array: ");
        double values = input.nextDouble();
        numbers[i][j] = values;
    }
}
```

This way, you're adding entries into your 2D array by filling each row starting from the first row (at index `0`) until you reach the last row (at index `i-1`). And while you're filling each row, you start filling the columns one by one by starting at the first column (at index `0`) until you reach the last column (at index `j-1`).

Comment: My guess is that OP just made a typo that he didn't notice

Comment: Thanks man that was my issue, problem staring me straight in the face but didn't even notice it, cheers.

Comment: @Daniel No problem. If you found the answer helpful then don't forget to upvote or accept the answer. Good luck coding!

Answer (score 1):

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are exceeding the elements. Please be aware that 0 can also be an item in an array.

For example:

```
array[0] = "Hey";
array[1] = "Sup! wow... just wow";
```

If I did

```
system.out.println(array[2]);
```

It would print the error

But if i did

```
system.out.println(array[0], array[1]);
```

It would work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code here :

```
numbers[rows][columns] = values;
```

I believe you meant

```
numbers[i][j] = values;
```

Thanks